# How to implement a Search functionality in Liferay Custom Theme

Tags: liferay-6

I have writeen custom Theme under the portal_normal.vm i have the below thing

The below is basically responsible for a Search Functionality

My requirment is that on click of a search button by the user , i need to call the Database and provide the search results .

I am in a confusion as the Theme doesn't got any portlet.xml file , so how can i call my method ??

This is how it is looking currently .

[image]

Comment: You can embed your custom portlet in theme , in portal_normal.vm file using $theme.runtime('yourportletid')

Comment: Hey Pankaj, since you are answering this question, why don't you post it as answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following in portal_normal.vm file

```
$theme.search()
```

Also you can customize the search criteria. you need to specify it in portal-ext.properties file.